# Access: between in iif

Tags: ms-access

I'm working with an Access query embeded in a form.

This is my criteria statement:

```
Like IIf(IsNull([Formularze]![WyszukiwarkaPomyslow]![tbDataPoczatek]);"*";Between #2016-01-01# And #2016-12-31#)
```

I want the query to return all records if the `tbDataPoczatek` is empty and if `tbDataPoczatek` is anything else I want the query to return all dates between 2016-01-01 and 2016-12-31. The data format is EU.

The first part is ok. when empty the query returns all the records. But as soon as I type something into tbDataPoczatek and rerun the query, it returns 0 records.

Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: You can't use like and between - they are both operators. Try moving your Like into the IIf statement.

Comment: If you mean this:    IIf(IsNull([Formularze]![WyszukiwarkaPomyslow]![tbDataPoczatek]);Like "*";Between #2016-01-01# And #2016-12-31#)    it's not working ... furthermore it makes the wildcard to stop working as well :(

Comment: Use (Or is Null) in the where clause, as that will return all values. E.g. Between #2016-01-01# And #2016-12-31# OR ([Formularze]![WyszukiwarkaPomyslow]![tbDataPoczat‌​ek] IS  NULL)

Comment: That changs nothing

Comment: Okay - have a read here - there is an lot more information https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=59853